# A way to test that a function does NOT call exit, but returns normally, with gtest

Tags: googletest

I know there are "death" tests in gtest, for example the `EXPECT_EXIT(statement,...)` test which expects the statement to eventually call `exit(n)` or abort with a signal or something. This passes if the statement does call `exit()`, but fails if it simply `returns` from main.

What I was looking for was the opposite, something like `EXPECT_NO_EXIT(statement)` where the statement returns without calling `exit`, but simply returns a value.  The reason for this, is that if the statement does call `exit`, then the gtest harness just exits and the whole suite of tests stops immediately.

It doesn't have to be `EXPECT_NO_EXIT`, but a method to prevent a call to `exit` in the code-under-test from killing the gtest harness.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your statement into a code that will satisfy the assertion if the statement returns control to the caller:

```
EXPECT_EXIT(
  { statement; std::out << "function did not exit"; exit(0) },
  testing::ExitedWithCode(0),
  "function did not exit");
```